# React-Native, Redux, and Thunk: Async Function Executing Twice But Not Populating State

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk

After my previous attempt failed, I ran git stash and started over, and the code inside return (dispatch) finally executed. Unfortunately, it began to execute twice, but still not populate the state (or by executing twice it overwrote the state).

Here is my code:

DivisionManagement\index.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {View, FlatList, Alert} from "react-native";
import {withNavigation} from "react-navigation";
import {connect} from "react-redux";

import PortableButton from "./../../components/PortableButton";

import masterStyles, {listPage, bigButtonStyles} from "./../../styles/master";

import DivisionManagementRow from "./DivisionManagementRow";
import { loadDivisions } from "../../redux/actions/divisionActions";

class DivisionManagmementScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        console.log(`Entered componentDidMount(), props: ${JSON.stringify(this.props)}`);
        this.props.getAllDivisions(1);
        console.log(`props again: ${JSON.stringify(this.props)}`);
    }


    _renderItem = ({item}) => {
        console.log(`item: ${JSON.stringify(item)}`);
        return (
        <DivisionManagementRow divisionId={item.DIVISION_ID} divisionName={item.DIVISION_NAME}
            onAddTeam={() => {this._addTeam(item.DIVISION_ID)}}
            onEdit={() => {this._editDivision(item.DIVISION_ID)}}
            onDelete={() => {this._btnDeleteDivision(item.DIVISION_ID)}}/>        

    )};


    render() {
        console.log(`Props in render: ${JSON.stringify(this.props)}`);
        return (
            <View style={masterStyles.component}>
                <View style={listPage.listArea}>
                    <FlatList 
                        data={this.props.divisions}
                        renderItem={this._renderItem}
                        keyExtractor={(item) => item.DIVISION_ID.toString() } />
                </View>        
                <View style={listPage.bottomButtonArea}>
                    <PortableButton defaultLabel="Add Division"
                        disabled={false}
                        onPress={() => {this._addDivision()}}
                        onLongPress={() => {}}
                        style={bigButtonStyles} />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log(`State: ${JSON.stringify(state)}`);
    return {
        programId: state.programId,
        divisions: state.divisions,
        isLoading: state.isLoadingDivisions
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        getAllDivisions: (programId) => dispatch(loadDivisions(programId))
    };
}

export default withNavigation(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DivisionManagmementScreen));
```

divisionActions.js

```
import {query2} from "./../../util/DbUtils";

export const DIVISIONS_LOADING = "DIVISIONS_LOADING";
export const DIVISIONS_BY_PROGRAM = "DIVISIONS_BY_PROGRAM";
export const DIVISIONS_POPULATE = "DIVISIONS_POPULATE";

export function loadDivisions(programId) {
    console.log(`loadDivisions, programId: ${JSON.stringify(programId)}`);
    let result = (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(isLoadingDivisions(true));
        query2("SELECT * FROM DIVISION WHERE DIVISION_PROGRAM_ID = ?", [programId])
            .then((queryResults) => {
                console.log("Query results: " + JSON.stringify(queryResults));
                return queryResults;
            }).then((queryResults) => {
                dispatch(isLoadingDivisions(false));
                return queryResults;
            }).then((queryResults) => {
                console.log("Dispatching query results " + JSON.stringify(queryResults));
                dispatch(populateDivisions(queryResults.result));
                //return queryResults;
            });
    }
    return result;
}

export function isLoadingDivisions(value) {
    console.log(`Entered isLoadingDivisions, value: ${value}`);
    return {
        type: DIVISIONS_LOADING,
        payload: value
    }
}

export function getDivisionsByProgram(programId) {
    return {
        type: DIVISIONS_BY_PROGRAM,
        payload: programId
    }
}

export function populateDivisions(divisions) {
    console.log(`populateDivisions(), divisions: ${JSON.stringify(divisions)}`);
    return {
        type: DIVISIONS_POPULATE,
        payload: divisions
    }
}
```

divisionReducer.js

```
import { DIVISIONS_LOADING, DIVISIONS_BY_PROGRAM } from "../actions/divisionActions";
import {loadDivisions} from "../actions/divisionActions";

export function isLoadingDivisions(state = false, action) {
    console.log(`Entered isLoadingDivisions: ${JSON.stringify(action)}`);
    switch (action.type) {
        case DIVISIONS_LOADING:
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export function divisions(state = [], action) {
    console.log("Entered divisions()");
    switch (action.type) {
        case DIVISIONS_BY_PROGRAM:
        let divisions = loadDivisions(action.payload);
            console.log(`Divisions in divisions(): ${JSON.stringify(divisions)}`);
            return divisions;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

reducers\index.js

```
import {combineReducers} from "redux";

import {isLoadingDivisions, divisions} from "./divisionReducer";

export default rootReducer = combineReducers({
    isLoadingDivisions,
    divisions
});
```

What should be happening here is that state should have an entry:

```
{ divisions: // populated array }
```

Instead, I'm getting this:

```
{ divisions: [] }
```

(The second one corresponds with the initial state, so maybe it's being overwritten?)

So I have one, or potentially two, problems with this code:

1. It's executing twice according to the logs
2. the divisions array in the state is not populating.

Can anyone help?